# Stopping an infinite flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a server that relays between two (different) clients. When the User (first client, through websockets) sends a message, the server needs to repeat this message every X milliseconds to the Device (second client) until a new message is received, or the websocket is closed.

I consume the websocket as a flow, and I've created the following operator:

```kotlin
fun <T> flowEvery(value: T, everMilliSeconds: Long): Flow<T> =
    flow {
        while (true) {
            emit(value)
            delay(everMilliSeconds)
        }
    }.cancellable()

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun <T> Flow<T>.repeatEvery(mSec: Long): Flow<T> =
    this.flatMapLatest {
        flowEvery(it, mSec)
    }
```

Problem is, once the socket is closed the last message is kept on being sent for ever.

My call site is:

```kotlin
try {
    oscConnections.sendTo(
        deviceIdentifier,
        incoming.consumeAsFlow().repeatEvery(50).mapNotNull { frame ->
            when (frame) {
                is Frame.Text -> listOf(frame.readText().toFloat())
                else -> null
            }
        })
} finally {
    close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.NORMAL, "Ended"))
}
```

the `incoming` channel is closed (`onCompletion` is called) but the stream sent to `sendTo` is not. `sendTo` it self consumes the input stream and send a UDP message for every element it consumes.

How can I force the flow to stop?

Comment: My current solution is to add `incoming.onCompletion { throw TerminateException() }` and then catch it down the stream, forcing it close, but it seems to me like a bad usage for exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `flatMapLatest` or `transformLatest` you replace the last value of the upstream Flow with a never-ending Flow.

You must stop that Flow somehow and `CancellationException`s are used everywhere in coroutines to signal the cancellation of coroutines. You can wrap your never-ending Flow logic in a `coroutineScope` to precisely cancel only that scope once the upstream flow has completed.

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.repeatEvery(delay: Long): Flow<T> =
    flow<T> {
        try {
            coroutineScope {
                onCompletion { this@coroutineScope.cancel() }
                    .transformLatest { value ->
                        while (true) {
                            emit(value)
                            delay(delay)
                        }
                    }
                    .collect(::emit)
            }
        }
        catch (e: CancellationException) {
            // done
        }
    }
```

PS: `.cancellable()` doesn't do much in your example. As per documentation Flows built using flow builders like `flow { … }` are automatically cancellable.